# Gatsby unable to create multiple child sections from GraphQL queries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm using Craft CMS headless mode with Gatsby and i'm trying to generate 2 sets of pages from the GraphQL data output by Craft. One section is posts which i intend to be "/notes/note-slug" and one is projects intended to be "/work/project-slug".

After setting up my gatsby-node.js file as close to what i expect to work as possible, Gatsby kicks off and gives me an error of 'Cannot read property 'id' of undefined' on the projects section.

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const projectTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/project.js`)
  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/note.js`)

  return graphql(`
    {
      craft {
        projects: entries(section: "work") {
          id
          slug
        }
        blogPosts: entries(section: "notes") {
          id
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      Promise.reject(result.errors)
    }

    // Create all single project pages
    result.data.craft.projects.forEach(({ project }) => {
      createPage({
        path: `/work/${project.slug}`,
        component: projectTemplate,
        context: {
          id: Number(project.id),
          slug: project.slug,
        },
      })
    })

    // Create all single note pages
    result.data.craft.blogPosts.forEach(({ note }) => {
      createPage({
        path: `/notes/${note.slug}`,
        component: blogPostTemplate,
        context: {
          id: Number(note.id),
          slug: note.slug,
        },
      })
    })

    return Promise.resolve()
  })
}
```

My GraphQL query is sound, after testing the same query within my gatsby-node.js file, this is what is returned.

```
{
  "data": {
    "craft": {
      "projects": [
        {
          "id": "34",
          "slug": "some-slug"
        },
        {
          "id": "130",
          "slug": "have-a-slug"
        }
      ],
      "blogPosts": [
        {
          "id": "15",
          "slug": "another-slug"
        },
        {
          "id": "27",
          "slug": "one-slug"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm struggling to see where i've gone wrong here, both section's slugs and id's are available yet the error is referring to:

`gatsby-node.js:31 result.data.craft.projects.forEach`

Apologies if there's not enough context here, i'll try and supply more if required. First question on StackOverflow so just learning the ropes :D

Comment: Try `console.log(result)` before `forEach` and `console.log(project)` inside `forEach`. Is the GraphQL object graph as you expected?